# How can I save CPU usage in a variable on FreeBSD?

Tags: shell, sh, freebsd, pfsense

I want to display my CPU usage in a command, take it the percentage and assign to a variable.

Also, it could be form to calculate that.
maybe a way occupying top.

Comment: ....if you tried it for days, what exactly have you tried? Using just some seconds of googling, I found many different ways that could work

Comment: i tried learn grep and awk on top command. also i searched cpu information with sysctl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
vmstat | awk 'NR==3 {print $(NF-2)" "$(NF-1)" "$(NF)}'
```

You'll have three values: user, system and idle percentages. If you don't need any of them you can modify the `awk`-script.